# Search with a joined table using YII

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the following table structure.
tb_posts has the field author_id which relates to tb_author.id
in YII i have the following in my posts activeRecord

```
public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'authorRelation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'authorRecord', 'author')
    );
}
```

How i do a search of posts of an authors with name 'foo'? I am trying the following with no success

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('authorRelation');
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->compare( 'author.name', 'foo', true );
$posts=PostsRecord::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set table alias for your models at init.

```
class PostsRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    // ...
    public function init() { $this->setTableAlias( 'postsrecord' ); }
    // ...
}

class AuthorRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    // ...
    public function init() { $this->setTableAlias( 'authorrecord' ); }
    // ...
}
```

Finally:

```
$condition=new CDbCriteria;
$condition->with = array('authorRelation');
$condition->together = true;
$condition->condition = 'authorrecord.name=:authorname';
$condition->params = array( ':authorname' => 'foo' );
$posts=PostsRecord::model()->findAll($condition);
```

Comment: Actualy using authorRelation,name did the trick in the condition, the rest of the code seemed to work fine, thanks

Comment: Have to point out, that `$condition->condition` should be replaced with `$condition->addSearchCondition(...)` (noticed just now the `true` value in `$criteria->compare( 'author.name', 'foo', true );`)

Comment: `compare()` will call `addSearchCondition()`, but will make various checks before that. Where `addSearchCondition()` is _exacly_ what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks boris, you have been really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your relation should be `'authorRelation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'authorRecord', author_id')`. The 3rd parameter is the foreign key.

The second part of the code doesn't have any errors, the search should work if you set up the relations correctly.